# How can I list all the users who liked a post in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to django rest framework and I am trying to list all the users who have liked particular posts, but here I am getting only a empty dictionary. I may have my views or serializers wrong, can anyone check the code out and suggest the changes I should make?

```
class LikeListApiView(APIView):
    serializer_class = PostLikeListSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        likes_list = post.likes.all()
        serializer = PostLikeListSerializer(likes_list)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['username',]

class PostLikeListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True) #likes is in Post model with foreign key to user Model
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['likes',]
```

Please let me know if further details are needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you pass on your PostLikeSerializer a Account object, not Post object

replace

```
try:
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
except Post.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
likes_list = post.likes.all()
serializer = PostLikeListSerializer(likes_list)
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

by

```
try:
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
except Post.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
serializer = PostLikeListSerializer(post) # <-- here you pass post object
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

edit:

and you can remove your get methods to check if post exist , ModelViewSet do this for you
so this is working exactly same:

```
class LikeListApiView(modelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostLikeListSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Comment: But queryset is for all the posts right? so how will I be able to see the users who liked a particular post?

Comment: you can add filter_set in class , you when you request your api , you add user in queryparams  like :  ajax.get('api/post?likes__user=myuser')